# Http Post Headers in tcl -> 400 bad request

Tags: rest, http, post, header, tcl

I am trying to send an http post request using tcl. My code is as following:

```
proc ::rest::setRequest {req} {
    upvar $req str
    set str  "POST domain.com HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    append str "Host: blablabla\r\n"
    append str "Content-Length:11\r\n"
    append str "Content-Type:text/xml\r\n"
    append str "Authorization: Basic ZGVmYXVsdDpkZWZhdWx0\r\n\r\n"
}

proc ::rest::sendRestMsg {ip port request} {


    set chan [socket $ip $port]
    puts $chan $request
    flush $chan
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"
    puts "[gets $chan]"


}
```

My problem is that the server parser keep telling me HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request, HTTP header lexer error at character '
' (0xd) before buf_p=0x5b8c7074 offset=32.

It complains from from "\n" on the first line. What is wrong with my headers?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl translates the input and output on channels so that you can use `\n` inside scripts (possibly implicitly, via `puts`) and yet have the right newline style for the platform used when the bytes hit the OS. It mostly gets things right by default, but not always.

With a socket where you want `\r\n` as the separator, you should configure this explicitly.

```
set chan [socket $ip $port]
fconfigure $chan -translation crlf
# You might also need to configure the character -encoding
```

After that, you can just pretend everything is simple and it should all “just work”.

Failing that, if you want precise control over what bytes are sent, change the translation to `binary` and use `puts -nonewline` to write exact byte sequences:

```
fconfigure $chan -translation binary
puts -nonewline $chan "these_are really raw_bytes\r\n"
```

The `binary format` command can help with creation of the messages, as can the `encoding convertto` command; both yield byte-arrays (a special string with characters in it that conveniently correspond to bytes).

Answer (score 0):

i found the mistak socket buffer does not accept /r/n. So to get it working write the request line by line